# How to give arguments for Read Csv As Dictionary in robot framework

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, automation, robotframework

I am using RIDE 1.7.3.1 running on Python 3.7.5. Iam doing migration process frpm python 27 to python 37 . in python 27 i have used the key word read csv file to associative to Read the csv file as a dictinary. For example if my csv file is

```
id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0
```

i want an output like the following

```
{'age': '20', 'height': '62', 'id': '1', 'weight': '120.6', 'name': 'Alice'}     
{'age': '21', 'height': '74', 'id': '2', 'weight': '190.6', 'name': 'Freddie'}     
{'age': '17', 'height': '68', 'id': '3', 'weight': '120.0', 'name': 'Bob'}
```

In python 37 csvlib 1.0.0 is only supported.
it contains the following keywords

```
Read CSV As Single List
Read CSV As List
Read CSV As Dictionary
```

I am using the following libraries.

```
pip freeze

Appium-Python-Client==0.48
bcrypt==3.1.7
beautifulsoup4==4.8.1
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
coverage==4.5.4
cryptography==2.8
decorator==4.4.1
docutils==0.15.2
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==0.23
jsonpatch==1.24
jsonpath-rw==1.4.0
jsonpath-rw-ext==1.2.2
jsonpointer==2.0
kitchen==1.2.6
more-itertools==7.2.0
numpy==1.17.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
paramiko==2.6.0
pbr==5.4.3
Pillow==6.2.1
pluggy==0.13.0
ply==3.11
py==1.8.0
pycparser==2.19
Pygments==2.4.2
PyNaCl==1.3.0
PyPubSub==3.3.0
pywin32==227
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
robotframework==3.1.2
robotframework-appiumlibrary==1.5.0.4
robotframework-csvlib==1.0.0
robotframework-extendedrequestslibrary==0.5.5
robotframework-ftplibrary==1.6
robotframework-httplibrary==0.4.2
robotframework-jsonlibrary==0.3.1
robotframework-requests==0.6.2
robotframework-ride==1.7.3.1
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.1.0
robotframework-sshlibrary==3.4.0
robotframeworklexer==1.1
scp==0.13.2
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.13.0
soupsieve==1.9.5
tox==3.0.0
urllib3==1.25.7
virtualenv==16.7.7
waitress==1.3.1
WebOb==1.8.5
WebTest==2.0.33
wxPython==4.0.7.post2
zipp==0.6.0
```

Could you give the solution to get the output like above.

Comment: What do you mean with keywords? Methods? Please post the code, where you read the csv and the error you get if you use Python 3.7.

Comment: in python 27 i have used csvlibrary==0.0.2

Comment: there is a keyword in csvlibrary(0.0.2) Read Csv File To Associative to read the csv file as a dictionary. my code is ```@{dict}= Read Csv File To Associative ${file name} delimiter=, ```.

Comment: In python 37 the above csv library version is not supported. I am using svlib 1.0.0. It contains the following keywords ```Read CSV As Single List
Read CSV As List
Read CSV As Dictionary```

Comment: if i replece the keyword as read csv as dictionary how can i give the arguments for this keyword

Comment: What is your actual question here? The title says `How to give arguments for Read Csv As Dictionary in robot framework`, but in the question part you try to find a complete solution, not the description of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the documentation of [robotframework-csvlib](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-csvlib/) 1.0.0

The `Read CSV As Dictionary` keyword documentation is as follows:

> Read CSV As Dictionary
>
> ```
> Arguments:
>     Filepath
>     Name of key column
>     Name(s) of value column(s)
>     Delimiter (optional)
> Returns:
>     A dictionary with the key column a key and the value column(s) as value. 
>     If there are multiple value columns the value will be a list containing all values.
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> *** Settings ***
> Library  CSVLib    
> *** Test Cases ***
> Test CSV
>     ${singlelist}=      Read CSV As Single List     test.csv
>     log to console      ${singlelist}    
>     ${list}=        read csv as list        test.csv
>     log to console      ${list}    
>     ${dict}=        read csv as dictionary      test_dict.csv       Animal      Legs        ,
>     log to console      ${dict}    
>     ${value}=       create list         Legs            Eyes
>     ${dictWList}=       read csv as dictionary      test_dict1.csv      Animal      ${value}    ,
>     log to console      ${dictWList}
> ```

Comment: yeah.. but i dont know how to give arguments for this keyword. can you say how can i give arguments for this type of csv file. ```id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0``` And i want the dictionary as ```{'age': '20', 'height': '62', 'id': '1', 'weight': '120.6', 'name': 'Alice'}     
{'age': '21', 'height': '74', 'id': '2', 'weight': '190.6', 'name': 'Freddie'}     
{'age': '17', 'height': '68', 'id': '3', 'weight': '120.0', 'name': 'Bob'}    ```

Comment: I'm quite sure that does not work just by one keyword call because you have keys as the first row of the input. Most likely you'll have to fetch the input and then loop and construct keys from the first row of your input CSV.